# Understanding Ruby for a C# developer

Tags: c#, ruby

How exactly is a Ruby application architecture?

What are the different filetypes and their content?
What is the extension for a solution/project file?
Which file is analogous to a config file?
Are there files like DLLS formed?
If there is not a main() defined, what is the entrypoint for a program?

I looked up on the internet for all of this. But all I could find are some command line tiny code snippets or some tutorial to put Ruby on Rails.

Comment: Are you looking for information about ruby, ruby on rails, or both?

Comment: You really need to just run through a Ruby tutorial, because you don't seem to know anything about the language. There are plenty available that don't mention Rails. Just to answer a few of your questions: Ruby is an interpreted language, so the ruby interpreter uses *.rb files. No solutions or compiled code - no DLLs. Ruby code just starts running at the beginning.

Comment: To people downvoting this question: while I agree that he's asking a lot and seems to have neglected even the most rudimentary investigation, it's still a valid question. Learning to program (I doubt his knowledge of C# is very deep at all) can be a daunting task.

Comment: @chance, yes it's a valid question, but really not one that should be asked here. I think answer 2 of the FAQs sums it up pretty well.

Comment: @AnthonyDeSimone I guess. I never really understood that "rule." I've stumbled upon a number of perfectly valid questions, questions that deserved discussion and answers that were closed under that premise. In a field such as ours, sometimes "chatty" questions are the most important. But this isn't the medium to debate such things.

Comment: @chance, I agree and enjoy, chatty open-ended questions. But as you pointed out, this isn't the venue for them.

Comment: @AnthonyDeSimone thank you. I got started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there files like DLLS formed?

No. Ruby is an [interpreted language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreted_language) much like JavaScript, Python, and PHP.

> If there is not a main() defined, what is the entrypoint for a program?

Well, what do you define as an entry point? If you mean running a particular file, then anything not wrapped in a class or method will be invoked.

> I looked up on the internet for all of this. But all I could find are some command line tiny code snippets or some tutorial to put Ruby on Rails.

I strongly recommend you start by getting a better understanding of what Ruby is and how it works before moving on to rails. You can either buy a book or the notorious Pickaxe book is online for free [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/).